# Mongodb GridFS having trouble downloading .ppt and .doc files?

Tags: php, mongodb, powerpoint, mime-types, gridfs

I have this function in my controller to download files that i am storing in my mongodb grid:

```
function download_presentation($ext,$store_filename)
{               
    $grid = $this->mongo->db->getGridFS();                      
    //query the file object
    $objects = $grid->find();
    //set content-type header, output in browser
    switch ($ext) {
        case 'pdf':
        $mimeType = 'Content-type: application/pdf';
        break;
        case 'jpg':
        $mimeType = 'Content-type: image/jpg';
        break;
        case 'png':
        $mimeType = 'Content-type: image/png';
            break;
        case 'doc':
        $mimeType = 'Content-type: application/msword';
        break;
        case 'docx':
        $mimeType = 'Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document';
        break;
        case 'xls':
        $mimeType = 'Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel';
        break;
        case 'xlsx':
        $mimeType = 'Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet';
        break;
        case 'ppt':
            $mimeType = 'Content-type: application/x-mspowerpoint';
        break;
            case 'pptx': $mimeType = 'Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-                           officedocument.presentationml.presentation';
        break;
        default:
        $mimeType='Content-type: application/pdf';
                            }
           while($object = $objects->getNext()) :
           if(($object->file['filename'])==$store_filename){                      
           $content=$object->getBytes();
           header("Content-Length: " . strlen($content)); 
           header($mimeType); 
           echo ($content);}            
           endwhile;
```

}
Whenever i am downloading .ppt files it is saying PowerPoint can't open this file beacuse it is not .ppt. For pptx files when i open it after downloading ,it is working when i am clicking on 'repair' pop up from PowerPoint.Same thing is happening with .doc/MS-Word.Only pdf files are running perfectly.
Can anyone please tell me what is the problem?

Comment: Try calling $object->[getSize](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-articles/nodekoarticle1.html) instead of using the strlen function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after a year and a whole lot of reading , understanding and implementing PHP i am able to answer my own question , I had fixed the error using [`ob_clean()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php) method and it worked like a charm , hope this helps someone in the future...

```
        $content= $object->getBytes();
        header("Content-Length: " . strlen($content)); 
        header($mimeType); 
        ob_clean(); 
        echo($content);
```

Comment: Could you let me know why there is a need to use `ob_clean` to empty the buffer ?

Comment: Also what if we use `ob_clean(); flush();`

Comment: ob_clean clears the buffer, before you can render the image ,also it clears stray spaces..

Comment: Your solution helped me in the same situation. Upvoted.

Comment: Normally this shouldn't happen because that means an early (and unintentional for sure) output was made somewhere in the script. Your solution helped me found out that, in my case, the invisible output was caused because of an UTF-8 file with UTF-8 characters.